# Selenium enforce full loading of webpage?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from Instagram with Selenium, but I need my program to fully load the page so it can actually access the data.

I'm looping through a list with urls and want to target the posts and followers numbers. So it looks something like:

```py
users = []
for i in urls:
        driver.get(i)
        sleep(1) #even with this sleep, it doesn't alway load enough of the page and I'd prefer not to sleep too long on every page
        header = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "_aa_6")
        number = header[0].text
        number = int(number.replace(f"\nposts",""))
        if number >= 10:
            followers = header[1].text
            tup = (url, followers)
            users.append(tup)
```

It works sometimes with the 1 second sleep but it's hit or miss. I was wondering if Selenium has some way to enforce the page to load. However, I wouldn't want to fully load each page either since it doesn't have to load the instagram pictures.

I'll do a while-loop to enforce the length of header but I was wondering if Selenium offers a better solution or maybe Selenium isn't the best tool for this kind of task?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium - wait until element is present, visible and interactable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use [explicit waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead of the so worse `time.sleep()`.

```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
    header = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_aa_6")))
    [...]
```

It will wait  until the element is located (aka loaded). I set it waits for a max of 30 seconds but of course it can be modified.

Comment: ah yes, that's the kind of thing I was looking for, thanks :)